# Display in gridview PHP

Tags: php, css, gridview

I have this column images. I want it to be displayed in gridview like the first row should be, 1 2 3 then the next is 4 5 6. How do I do that if I only have one variable name for all the images?

```
$output = json_decode($output);
foreach($output as $template) {
    echo '<a href='.$template->preview_url.' target="_blank"><img src=' . $template->thumbnail_url. '></a>';
    echo 'Name:' . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $template->template_name . '<br>';
    echo 'Description:'. '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $template->template_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$output = json_decode($output);

$i=1;
foreach($output as $template) 
{
    echo "<div style='float:left'>";
    echo '<a href='.$template->preview_url.' target="_blank"><img src=' . $template->thumbnail_url. '></a>';
    echo 'Name:' . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $template->template_name . '<br>';
    echo 'Description:'. '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $template->template_id;
    echo "</div>";

    if($i == 3)
    {
        echo "<div style='clear: both'></div>";
        $i=1;
    }
    $i++;
}
```